# Hoist static properties of function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to hoist static properties of a function.

I have this code:

```
console.log('Background.blah:', Background.blah);

Background.blah = 123;
function Background() {

}

console.log('Background.blah:', Background.blah);
```

The first console.log of Background.blah is undefined. Is there anyway to hoist that rather then pasting the assignment at the top?

Comment: Move the code up if you want it to run first.  The function is being hoisted, otherwise you would get an error.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: No. Assignments are never hoisted, only declarations are. Just write your code in the correct order.

Comment: I'm trying to imagine why anyone would ever use hoisting; it seems like a structurally unsound way of doing things.

Comment: @Bergi - is there anyway to declare this static property? Like at the same time the function is declared? This is what I am trying to accomplish, I don't want to assign blah, I want to declare it.

Comment: @Blagoh No, you cannot. Why would you want to?

Comment: Got it, @Bergi I was just curious.

Answer (score 0):

No, we can't. Hoisting is an automatic process, we can't control it. As i know, only variable declaration moves up, but not assignment.